# Beautiful Soup Returning Unwanted Characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I'm using Beautiful Soup to scrape pages trying to get the height of certain athletes:

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
height = soup.find_all("strong")
height = height[2].contents
print height
```

Unfortunately, this is what gets returned:

[u'6\'0"']

I've also tried:

```
height = str(height[2].contents)
```

and

```
height = unicode(height[2].contents)
```

but I still get [u'6\'0"'] as a result.

How can I just have 6'0" returned without the extra characters? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't "extra characters".  [`.contents` returns a list](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children), the element you chose only has one child, and so you're getting a list containing one element.  Python prints a list as pseudo Python code, so you can see what it is and what's in it.

Perhaps you want [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)?

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you very much!  :)

Comment: @CGul could you mark as the accepted answer, so the question doesn't look unanswered forever?  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the third *strong* tag you don't need to find everyone, you can use a css selector  `nth-of-type`, once you have the element you just need to call `.text`:

```
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
height = soup.select_one("strong:nth-of-type(3)").text

print(height)
```

You should also be calling `.content`,letting requests handle the encoding.